# Amazon RDS Aurora master/replica access restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am running a DB cluster with two instances at **Amazon RDS Aurora**. One instance is the *master*, the other instance is a read-only *replica*. The purpose of the replica is to allow a third party application access to certain tables of the database for reporting. Therefore, the reporting tool accesses the read-only cluster endpoint, which works perfectly fine. In order to achieve zero-downtime maintenance, AWS promotes the "replica" to be the "master" at any time. That's pretty cool and does not affect the reporting tool, because it accesses the cluster-ro endpoint, which always routes the traffic to the correct (read-only) replica.

However, this means I have to enable the "Publicly accessible: Yes" flag on both instances, so that the reporting tool (which is located outside the VPC) has access to all instances, because I can not predict which instance becomes the master or replica, correct?

I'd prefer, that the "master" instance (whatever instance that is) can only be accessed from inside the VPC. How can I achieve that?

My understand is that every change I do on the "master" instance, is automatically done on the replica(s), including adding/removing security groups for example. So if I open the firewall to allow access to the replica(s) for the reporting tool, the same IP addresses can also access the normal cluster endpoint and instance (not only the cluster-ro endpoint). How can I prevent that?

Comment: Michael, Is there anything else you'd like answered as part of this post?

Comment: No. Thanks Karthik for clarifying. I am using a restricted user with read-only access on a DB level already, but I was hoping that AWS offers the possibility to ensure, this user can not access the "master" instance at all.

Comment: It's a valid use case, I would suggest opening a case with AWS support to get this feature request added to the backlog. Aurora supports IAM based access control, and that should be extended to provide such granular access control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to build something custom for this unfortunately. Few options to consider from a design point of view are as follows:

Aurora cluster shares the security group settings across all instance like you called out. If you want to have custom settings, then what you could consider is making your whole cluster VPC only, and then have either ALBs or EC2 proxies that forward requests to your DB instance(s). You can then have multiple of these "proxies" and associate separate security groups for each of them.

One big callout with this sort of an architecture is that you need to make sure that you take care of failovers cleanly. Your proxies should always talk to the cluster endpoints and never to the instance endpoints, as instances can change from READER to WRITER behind the scenes. For example, ALBs do no let you create listeners that forward requests to a DNS, they only work with IPs. This means that you would need additional infrastructure to monitor the IPs of readers and writers and keep the ALB updated.

EC2 proxies are definitely a better option for such a design, with the caveat of added cost. I can go into more details if you have specific questions around this setup. This is definitely a summary of the approach, and not prod ready.

On the same note, why can't you use read restricted db users instead and keep the cluster public (with ssl enabled of course)?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a simpler solution might be to make the data accessible in some form outside the original cluster. You could set up a global database by doing 'add Region' in the console, creating a reader instance in a different AWS Region that also mirrors in real time all the data from your cluster. That instance could be small or large, whatever's needed to handle the reporting duties.

If the reporting application doesn't need 24x7 access to constantly update data: you can do 'create clone' and get a new cluster in a few minutes with the same data as the original one. When the report queries are finished, you can delete the clone. Then do the same thing again next time reports are needed. Some people automate that cycle on a schedule.

In both of those cases, you can set up connectivity to the other cluster independently from the original one.

Another technique I use sometimes is to have 3 instances. A writer and a reader in priority tier 0 so they can trade the writer role back and forth, and a third one in a lower priority tier so it's unlikely to be promoted to writer. However, that doesn't save you from the network and security complications for this particular scenario.

Remember that extra hardware resources you set up for reporting purposes can be downsized, stopped, or deleted when not needed.